# Dynamically change the color of jQuery Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery progress bar I want to theme (documentation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar#theming)) dynamically: it will start out red, then as it progresses turn yellow, and finally turn green. It seems like this would just be a matter of setting a style color attribute, but I can't seem to find what the appropriate attribute is.

Comment: Can't you add color when you change value of progressbar? i.e. $( ".selector" ).progressbar({ value: 37 }).css('color', 'green');

Comment: Just tried that. It doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Just realized that this actually initializes progress bar. You can try: $( ".selector" ).progressbar( "option", "value", 37 ).css('color', 'green');. And if it doesn't work, add css before .progressbar(..) (Though I don't think that would make any difference)

Comment: Alright, using your help I finally found the Google search terms to get the info I wanted. Apparently it works by setting the background color in an inner div, so instead of `$('#progressbar').css('color','red');` you have to use `$('#progressbar > div').css('background','red');`. Thanks for your help; I couldn't have found the answer without you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The jQuery UI progress bar doesn't have an explicitly set color; instead, it inherits the "widget header" background image from your UI theme.  The simplest way to change the color, then, is to set up styles which override the background.  For example:

```
.ui-progressbar.beginning .ui-progressbar-value { background: red; }
.ui-progressbar.middle .ui-progressbar-value { background: yellow; }
.ui-progressbar.end .ui-progressbar-value { background: green; }
```

(Alternatively, you could use different background images.)  Then, you simply change the class on the progress bar when setting its value:

```
function updateProgressbar(current, target) {
    var value = parseInt(current / target * 100);

    $progressbar
        .progressbar("value", value)
        .removeClass("beginning middle end")
        .addClass(value < 40 ? "beginning" : value < 80 ? "middle" : "end");
}
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQrnC/)