# div background based on % in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this in my html. I want to apply the background dynamically based on %.

If I pass 30, the 30% of the div should be green. If it's 60, 60% of the div should be green

```
    <div id="progress_bar" class="meter-bg">
        by default white
    </div>
```

by default its background white. But when I click the button.

```
    <input type="submit" value="30"/>
```

It has to apply 30% of the green color to the progress_bar. How can I do that in Jquery

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013067/dynamically-change-the-color-of-jquery-progress-bar ?

Comment: You could use the jQuery implementation here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#default. If you wanted to write your own you could use this as a reference. Note that the colours can be controlled by the jQuery theme.

Answer (score 2):

### background-size

You could use the [background-size property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) for browsers that support it.

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('#progress_bar').css('background-size', '30%');
});
```

### More compatible

Otherwise I would use a div within `#progress_bar` to contain the actual background like so:

```
<div id="progress_bar">
    <div id="progress_bar_line" class="meter-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can just set the width property of the inner div:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('#progress_bar_line').css('width', '30%');
});
```

Comment: Where "for browsers that support it" is a very important note here.

Comment: Please explain the downvote so we may all learn from your greater wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to overlay a div (div2) with a green background on top of the white div (div1) and set it's width to div2.width = div1.width * .30