# how to show progress bar in html with different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I want that progress bar should have three different let say from o t0 40 is blue 40 to 80 is red and from 80 to 100 is green.I have searched a lot but i am getting only simple bar moving.
is there any way to do this.

I am using following code which i got but it also does not move.

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: 37
  });
 });

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="progressbar"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You should try with this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013067/dynamically-change-the-color-of-jquery-progress-bar

Comment: @secretlm in this making all the background green i want the section wise if it initial it show red and then red along with green like thi s

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's in Jquery UI but you can simply use CSS and make 2 layers one will be mask and the other is image where 40% of it's width will be blue, ten 40-80 red and 80 - 100 green then you need to uncover it.

On JQuery you need to hide this mask and it'll show you the layer below.

I googled and I found topic where is answer to your question

[jQuery UI: How to change the color of a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476573/jquery-ui-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progressbar)

check it.

Comment: it is with different color but i want three different colors in single bar

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply this Css code to your #progressbar

```
#progressbar{
width:300px;height:14px;
 background-color:#00aeff;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#00aeff, endColorstr=#ff0000);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #00aeff 40%, #ff0000 80%,#2fff00 100%);
background-image:linear-gradient(left, #00aeff 40%, #ff0000 80%,#2fff00 100%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #00aeff 40%, #ff0000 80%,#2fff00 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #00aeff 40%, #ff0000 80%,#2fff00 100%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #00aeff 40%, #ff0000 80%,#2fff00 100%);
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(40%,#00aeff), color-stop(80%,#ff0000),color-stop(100%,#2fff00));}
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to hook in theo the Change event and check where the progress is and then recolor the bar from that. looking at [The API](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#event-change) it looks douable

Answer (score 0):

Two different approaches that come to mind (if you don't want to use the CSS3 gradients mentioned by chermanarun:

1. Background image: if you know how wide your progress bar is going to be, simply create a background graphic that has three colours set at the points you specify. Apply this background to the progress indicator.
2. Layered bars: this requires you to 'limit' the growth of the first two bars to the upper range of progress (so bar 1 can't get wider than 40%, bar 2 can't get wider than 80%). Use CSS positioning and z-indexing so that all thee bars have the same left/top position, and stack them (bar 1 on top, bar 2 in the middle, bar 3 on the bottom). As the bars grow with the loading progress, the first two will stop at their upper limit allowing the ones underneath to keep going, giving the illusion of seamless progress.

Comment: `#progressbar .ui-progressbar-value { background: blue url(path/to/your/image.png) no-repeat left top; }` This CSS should apply your image instead of the default grey gradient supplied by jQuery UI. Setting the bg colour to blue by default (change it to the hex code for the blue used in your image) allows time for the background image to be loaded in on slower connections.